# Hide the second element within a class

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<span class="fileactions">
    <a href="#" class="action" data-action="Download" original-title="">
        <img class="svg" src="/login/owncloud/core/img/actions/download.svg"> Download
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="action" data-action="Share" original-title="">
        <img class="svg" src="/login/owncloud/core/img/actions/share.svg"> Share
    </a>
</span>
```

The class fileactions contains 2 link elements. I want the 2nd one to be removed.

I have tried using this:

```
.fileactions a:nth-child(2) {
    display:none;
}

.fileactions [data-action="Share"] {
    display: none;
}
```

and none of these worked.

I am using owncloud and want to hide the option to share files when logged in as a user.

[image]

HERE IS THE [PAGE SOURCE](http://jsfiddle.net/AJ44V/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ng-csp ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ng-csp ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ng-csp ie ie8 lte9 lte8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ng-csp ie ie9 lte9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><html class="ng-csp ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html class="ng-csp"><!--<![endif]-->


    <head data-user="jhinton@lpc.com" data-requesttoken="80b052824521ca02c51b">
        <title>
            Files | ownCloud (jhinton@lpc.com)      </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=543672169">
                                <style>
                                        #content #controls{
                                         display:none;
                                        }
                                        .fileactions > a[data-action="Share"] {
    display:none; !important;
}
                                </style>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/login/owncloud/core/img/favicon.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/login/owncloud/core/img/favicon-touch.png" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/login/owncloud/remote.php/core.css?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/login/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/css/files.css?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/owncloud/index.php/core/js/config.js?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/owncloud/remote.php/core.js?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/owncloud/apps/files/js/file-upload.js?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/owncloud/apps/files/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/owncloud/apps/files/js/jquery.fileupload.js?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/owncloud/apps/files/js/jquery-visibility.js?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/owncloud/apps/files/js/filelist.js?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/owncloud/apps/files/js/fileactions.js?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/owncloud/apps/files/js/files.js?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/owncloud/apps/files/js/keyboardshortcuts.js?v=e36258b3c74f08054a974a5fe1703f9c"></script>
                    </head>

    <body id="body-user">
    <div id="notification-container">
        <div id="notification"></div>
    </div>
    <header><div id="header">
            <a href="/login/owncloud/index.php" title="" id="owncloud"><img class="svg"
                src="/login/owncloud/core/img/logo-wide.svg" alt="ownCloud" /></a>
            <div id="logo-claim" style="display:none;"></div>
            <ul id="settings" class="svg">
                <span id="expand">
                    <span id="expandDisplayName">jhinton@lpc.com</span>
                    <img class="svg" src="/login/owncloud/core/img/actions/caret.svg" />
                </span>
                <div id="expanddiv">
                                    <li>
                        <a href="/login/owncloud/index.php/settings/personal" title=""
                            >
                            <img class="svg" alt="" src="/login/owncloud/settings/img/personal.svg">
                            Profile                     </a>
                    </li>
                                    <li>
                        <a id="logout" href="/login/owncloud/index.php?logout=true">
                            <img class="svg" alt="" src="/login/owncloud/core/img/actions/logout.svg" />
                            Log out                     </a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>

            <form class="searchbox" action="#" method="post">
                <span style="color:white; position:absolute; right:40%; padding-top:8px; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px;">Green Cleaning Monthly Reports - TQ to You</span><input id="searchbox" class="svg" type="search" name="query"
                    value=""
                    autocomplete="off" x-webkit-speech />
            </form>
        </div></header>

        <nav><div id="navigation">
            <ul id="apps" class="svg">
                                    <li data-id="files_index">
                        <a href="/login/owncloud/index.php/apps/files" title=""
                             class="active">
                            <img class="icon svg" src="/login/owncloud/core/img/places/files.svg"/>
                            <span>
                                Files                           </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                            </ul>
        </div></nav>

        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <!--[if IE 8]><style>input[type="checkbox"]{padding:0;}table td{position:static !important;}</style><![endif]-->
<div id="controls" >
        <div class="crumb" data-dir=''>
        <a href="/login/owncloud/index.php/apps/files?dir=">
            <img src="/login/owncloud/core/img/places/home.svg" class="svg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="crumb last svg"
         data-dir='/Shared'>
    <a href="/login/owncloud/index.php/apps/files?dir=/Shared">Shared</a>
    </div>
            <div class="actions"><input type="button" disabled value="You don&rsquo;t have write permissions here."></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="dir" value="/Shared" id="dir">
        <input type="hidden" name="permissions" value="9" id="permissions">
</div>


<table id="filestable" data-allow-public-upload="yes">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id='headerName'>
                <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" />
                <span class='name'>Name</span>
                <span class='selectedActions'>
                                            <a href="" class="download">
                            <img class="svg" alt="Download"
                                 src="/login/owncloud/core/img/actions/download.svg" />
                            Download                        </a>
                                    </span>
            </th>
            <th id="headerSize">Size</th>
            <th id="headerDate">
                <span id="modified">Modified</span>
                <!--                    NOTE: Temporary fix to allow unsharing of files in root of Shared folder -->
                                            <span class="selectedActions"><a href="" class="delete-selected">
                            Unshare                         <img class="svg" alt="Unshare"
                                 src="/login/owncloud/core/img/actions/delete.svg" />
                        </a></span>
                                                </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fileList">
        <input type="hidden" id="disableSharing" data-status="">

    <tr data-id="120"
        data-file="CD1029%201775%20I%20Street%20NE"
        data-type="dir"
        data-mime="httpd/unix-directory"
        data-size='6318729'
        data-permissions='17'>
        <td class="filename svg"
                    style="background-image:url(/login/owncloud/core/img/filetypes/folder.png)"
                    >
        <input type="checkbox" />                   <a class="name" href="/login/owncloud/index.php/apps/files?dir=/Shared/CD1029%201775%20I%20Street%20NE" title="">
                    <span class="nametext">
                                    CD1029 1775 I Street NE                         </span>
                            <span class="uploadtext" currentUploads="0">
                </span>
                        </a>
        </td>
        <td class="filesize"
            title="6 MB"
            style="color:rgb(187,187,187)">
                6.0     </td>
        <td class="date">
            <span class="modified"
                  title="December  3, 2013 09:23"
                  style="color:rgb(17,17,17)">
                yesterday           </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="121"
        data-file="CD1037%201015%2015th%20Street%20NW"
        data-type="dir"
        data-mime="httpd/unix-directory"
        data-size='7704440'
        data-permissions='17'>
        <td class="filename svg"
                    style="background-image:url(/login/owncloud/core/img/filetypes/folder.png)"
                    >
        <input type="checkbox" />                   <a class="name" href="/login/owncloud/index.php/apps/files?dir=/Shared/CD1037%201015%2015th%20Street%20NW" title="">
                    <span class="nametext">
                                    CD1037 1015 15th Street NW                          </span>
                            <span class="uploadtext" currentUploads="0">
                </span>
                        </a>
        </td>
        <td class="filesize"
            title="7.3 MB"
            style="color:rgb(185,185,185)">
                7.3     </td>
        <td class="date">
            <span class="modified"
                  title="November 15, 2013 10:04"
                  style="color:rgb(200,200,200)">
                19 days ago         </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="156"
        data-file="CD1113%202030%20M%20St"
        data-type="dir"
        data-mime="httpd/unix-directory"
        data-size='6395172'
        data-permissions='17'>
        <td class="filename svg"
                    style="background-image:url(/login/owncloud/core/img/filetypes/folder.png)"
                    >
        <input type="checkbox" />                   <a class="name" href="/login/owncloud/index.php/apps/files?dir=/Shared/CD1113%202030%20M%20St" title="">
                    <span class="nametext">
                                    CD1113 2030 M St                            </span>
                            <span class="uploadtext" currentUploads="0">
                </span>
                        </a>
        </td>
        <td class="filesize"
            title="6.1 MB"
            style="color:rgb(187,187,187)">
                6.1     </td>
        <td class="date">
            <span class="modified"
                  title="November 22, 2013 13:05"
                  style="color:rgb(169,169,169)">
                12 days ago         </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="157"
        data-file="CD1114%201724%20Mass%20Ave"
        data-type="dir"
        data-mime="httpd/unix-directory"
        data-size='6906485'
        data-permissions='17'>
        <td class="filename svg"
                    style="background-image:url(/login/owncloud/core/img/filetypes/folder.png)"
                    >
        <input type="checkbox" />                   <a class="name" href="/login/owncloud/index.php/apps/files?dir=/Shared/CD1114%201724%20Mass%20Ave" title="">
                    <span class="nametext">
                                    CD1114 1724 Mass Ave                            </span>
                            <span class="uploadtext" currentUploads="0">
                </span>
                        </a>
        </td>
        <td class="filesize"
            title="6.6 MB"
            style="color:rgb(186,186,186)">
                6.6     </td>
        <td class="date">
            <span class="modified"
                  title="November 22, 2013 13:35"
                  style="color:rgb(168,168,168)">
                12 days ago         </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="122"
        data-file="CV1028%203434%20Washington%20Blvd"
        data-type="dir"
        data-mime="httpd/unix-directory"
        data-size='8281090'
        data-permissions='17'>
        <td class="filename svg"
                    style="background-image:url(/login/owncloud/core/img/filetypes/folder.png)"
                    >
        <input type="checkbox" />                   <a class="name" href="/login/owncloud/index.php/apps/files?dir=/Shared/CV1028%203434%20Washington%20Blvd" title="">
                    <span class="nametext">
                                    CV1028 3434 Washington Blvd                         </span>
                            <span class="uploadtext" currentUploads="0">
                </span>
                        </a>
        </td>
        <td class="filesize"
            title="7.9 MB"
            style="color:rgb(184,184,184)">
                7.9     </td>
        <td class="date">
            <span class="modified"
                  title="November 14, 2013 09:28"
                  style="color:rgb(200,200,200)">
                20 days ago         </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="editor"></div>
<div id="uploadsize-message" title="Upload too large">
    <p>
    The files you are trying to upload exceed the maximum size for file uploads on this server. </p>
</div>
<div id="scanning-message">
    <h3>
        Files are being scanned, please wait. <span id='scan-count'></span>
    </h3>
    <p>
        Current scanning <span id='scan-current'></span>
    </p>
</div>

<!-- config hints for javascript -->
<input type="hidden" name="allowZipDownload" id="allowZipDownload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="usedSpacePercent" id="usedSpacePercent" value="0" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the [javascript](http://totalqualitybuildingservices.com/login/owncloud/apps/files/js/fileactions.js) making the darn thing

```
var FileActions = {
    actions: {},
    defaults: {},
    icons: {},
    currentFile: null,
    register: function (mime, name, permissions, icon, action) {
        if (!FileActions.actions[mime]) {
            FileActions.actions[mime] = {};
        }
        if (!FileActions.actions[mime][name]) {
            FileActions.actions[mime][name] = {};
        }
        FileActions.actions[mime][name]['action'] = action;
        FileActions.actions[mime][name]['permissions'] = permissions;
        FileActions.icons[name] = icon;
    },
    setDefault: function (mime, name) {
        FileActions.defaults[mime] = name;
    },
    get: function (mime, type, permissions) {
        var actions = {};
        if (FileActions.actions.all) {
            actions = $.extend(actions, FileActions.actions.all);
        }
        if (type) {//type is 'dir' or 'file'
            if (FileActions.actions[type]) {
                actions = $.extend(actions, FileActions.actions[type]);
            }
        }
        if (mime) {
            var mimePart = mime.substr(0, mime.indexOf('/'));
            if (FileActions.actions[mimePart]) {
                actions = $.extend(actions, FileActions.actions[mimePart]);
            }
            if (FileActions.actions[mime]) {
                actions = $.extend(actions, FileActions.actions[mime]);
            }
        }
        var filteredActions = {};
        $.each(actions, function (name, action) {
            if (action.permissions & permissions) {
                filteredActions[name] = action.action;
            }
        });
        return filteredActions;
    },
    getDefault: function (mime, type, permissions) {
        if (mime) {
            var mimePart = mime.substr(0, mime.indexOf('/'));
        }
        var name = false;
        if (mime && FileActions.defaults[mime]) {
            name = FileActions.defaults[mime];
        } else if (mime && FileActions.defaults[mimePart]) {
            name = FileActions.defaults[mimePart];
        } else if (type && FileActions.defaults[type]) {
            name = FileActions.defaults[type];
        } else {
            name = FileActions.defaults.all;
        }
        var actions = this.get(mime, type, permissions);
        return actions[name];
    },
    display: function (parent) {
        FileActions.currentFile = parent;
        var actions = FileActions.get(FileActions.getCurrentMimeType(), FileActions.getCurrentType(), FileActions.getCurrentPermissions());
        var file = FileActions.getCurrentFile();
        if ($('tr[data-file="'+file+'"]').data('renaming')) {
            return;
        }

        // recreate fileactions
        parent.children('a.name').find('.fileactions').remove();
        parent.children('a.name').append('<span class="fileactions" />');
        var defaultAction = FileActions.getDefault(FileActions.getCurrentMimeType(), FileActions.getCurrentType(), FileActions.getCurrentPermissions());

        var actionHandler = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            FileActions.currentFile = event.data.elem;
            var file = FileActions.getCurrentFile();

            event.data.actionFunc(file);
        };

        var addAction = function (name, action) {
            // NOTE: Temporary fix to prevent rename action in root of Shared directory
            if (name === 'Rename' && $('#dir').val() === '/Shared') {
                return true;
            }

            if ((name === 'Download' || action !== defaultAction) && name !== 'Delete') {
                var img = FileActions.icons[name];
                if (img.call) {
                    img = img(file);
                }
                               if(name==='Download'){
                var html = '<a href="#" class="action" data-action="' + name + '">';
}if(name === 'Share'){
var html = '<span class="sharing"><a href="#" class="action sharing" data-action="' + name + '">';
}
                if (img) {
                    html += '<img class ="svg" src="' + img + '" />';
                }
                html += t('files', name) + '</a></span>';

                var element = $(html);
                element.data('action', name);
                //alert(element);
                element.on('click', {a: null, elem: parent, actionFunc: actions[name]}, actionHandler);
                parent.find('a.name>span.fileactions').append(element);
            }

        };

        $.each(actions, function (name, action) {
            if (name !== 'Share') {
                addAction(name, action);
            }
        });
        if(actions.Share && !($('#dir').val() === '/' && file === 'Shared')){
            // t('files', 'Share')
            addAction('Share', actions.Share);
        } 

        // remove the existing delete action
        parent.parent().children().last().find('.action.delete').remove();
        if (actions['Delete']) {
            var img = FileActions.icons['Delete'];
            if (img.call) {
                img = img(file);
            }
            if (typeof trashBinApp !== 'undefined' && trashBinApp) {
                var html = '<a href="#" original-title="' + t('files', 'Delete permanently') + '" class="action delete" />';
            } else {
                var html = '<a href="#" original-title="' + t('files', 'Delete') + '" class="action delete" />';
            }
            var element = $(html);
            if (img) {
                element.append($('<img class ="svg" src="' + img + '"/>'));
            }
            element.data('action', actions['Delete']);
            element.on('click', {a: null, elem: parent, actionFunc: actions['Delete']}, actionHandler);
            parent.parent().children().last().append(element);
        }
    },
    getCurrentFile: function () {
        return FileActions.currentFile.parent().attr('data-file');
    },
    getCurrentMimeType: function () {
        return FileActions.currentFile.parent().attr('data-mime');
    },
    getCurrentType: function () {
        return FileActions.currentFile.parent().attr('data-type');
    },
    getCurrentPermissions: function () {
        return FileActions.currentFile.parent().data('permissions');
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#allowZipDownload').val() == 1) {
        var downloadScope = 'all';
    } else {
        var downloadScope = 'file';
    }

    if (typeof disableDownloadActions == 'undefined' || !disableDownloadActions) {
        FileActions.register(downloadScope, 'Download', OC.PERMISSION_READ, function () {
            return OC.imagePath('core', 'actions/download');
        }, function (filename) {
            window.location = OC.filePath('files', 'ajax', 'download.php') + '?files=' + encodeURIComponent(filename) + '&dir=' + encodeURIComponent($('#dir').val());
        });
    }
    $('#fileList tr').each(function () {
        FileActions.display($(this).children('td.filename'));
    });

    $('#fileList').trigger(jQuery.Event("fileActionsReady"));

});

FileActions.register('all', 'Delete', OC.PERMISSION_DELETE, function () {
    return OC.imagePath('core', 'actions/delete');
}, function (filename) {
    if (Files.cancelUpload(filename)) {
        if (filename.substr) {
            filename = [filename];
        }
        $.each(filename, function (index, file) {
            var filename = $('tr').filterAttr('data-file', file);
            filename.hide();
            filename.find('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
            filename.removeClass('selected');
        });
        procesSelection();
    } else {
        FileList.do_delete(filename);
    }
    $('.tipsy').remove();
});

// t('files', 'Rename')
FileActions.register('all', 'Rename', OC.PERMISSION_UPDATE, function () {
    return OC.imagePath('core', 'actions/rename');
}, function (filename) {
    FileList.rename(filename);
});


FileActions.register('dir', 'Open', OC.PERMISSION_READ, '', function (filename) {
    window.location = OC.linkTo('files', 'index.php') + '?dir=' + encodeURIComponent($('#dir').val()).replace(/%2F/g, '/') + '/' + encodeURIComponent(filename);
});

FileActions.setDefault('dir', 'Open');
```

Comment: This is a direct copy-paste of your code, and seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/49aKq/

Comment: Yes dude your second options is working correctly http://jsfiddle.net/zT9mc/1/

Comment: When I include it in the styling of the page it does nothing. =/
That little menu for download and share shows up when you hover..

Comment: @MarquézSantos then I suggest you use the DOM inspector (F12 in most browsers) to see what rules are applied to the element, and if anything is overriding it.

Comment: @Sachin check edits I made to original post. The fileactions.js is probably what is making things harder.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, your selector `.fileactions a:nth-child(2)` should work just fine, maybe there's more HTML in there you're not sharing, making the second a not be the second child?

If so you could try `.fileactions > a:nth-of-type(2)` instead, or even better, select based on the data attribute:

```
.fileactions > a[data-action="Share"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: `nth-of-type` lack of browser support :P

Comment: @Sachin `:nth-of-type()` has the same browser support as `:nth-child()` - but I agree that the attribute selector is a better option, or even the `a + a` as suggested by ravimallya (assuming there's never more than two buttons)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following

```
.fileactions a + a { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.fileactions > a[data-action="Share"] {
  display: none;
  !important;
}
```

It will not work !Why? Because `.fileactions>a[data-action="share"]` will find the first `a` tag within the `.fileactions` class. This is called child combinator one of four combinator of css.

Use this to get the desire result

```
.fileactions > a:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

or use attribute selector  to match the condition

```
[data-action="Share"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second answer works. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/8zQMU/)

But you may need to up the specificity because of another stylesheet.

You can do this by adding important as I have done below, or adding more elements to the selector.

```
.fileactions a:nth-child(2){
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: check original post. I noted more details of the situation

Answer (score 0):

for me

```
.fileactions a:nth-child(2){

 display:none;

}
```

is working fine, you could also try:

```
.fileactions a[data-action="Share"]{

 display:none;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try an attribute based selector?

```
.fileactions [data-action="Share"]{
  display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child` pseudo class won't work in IE 8 or in IE7, for that you can use ugly hack like this:

```
.fileactions a+a{
 display:none;
}
.fileactions a:nth-child(2){
 display:none;
}
```

example: http://jsbin.com/ivoMIkuM/1/edit . If both are not worked, try adding `!important` to `display:none` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use General Sibling Selector "~" (tilde) as below:

```css
a.action ~ a.action {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="fileactions">
    <a href="#" class="action" data-action="Download" original-title="">
        <img class="svg" src="/login/owncloud/core/img/actions/download.svg"> Download
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="action" data-action="Share" original-title="">
        <img class="svg" src="/login/owncloud/core/img/actions/share.svg"> Share
    </a>
</span>
```

This will make any `a.action` after first `a.action` hidden, where all the `a.action` belongs to same parent.