# Hide an element in a class - where do I add the code to hide the element?

Tags: javascript, css, owncloud

I've discovered this post which is almost exactly what I want to accomplish on my Owncloud server - [Hide the second element within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383160/hide-the-second-element-within-a-class)

from the suggested answers (there are many), the last comment said the following was needed:

```
.fileactions > a:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

My question is...where do I put this bit of code? I can't tell from the answer where to put this?  I have a .js file in Owncloud called fileactionsSpec.js.  It's the only place where I've found code with the words action-download in them.  Do I add this code:

```
.fileactions > a:nth-child(2) {
   display: none;
}
```

To the end of that .js file?

Thanks.

Comment: Ahhh I see now...I had thought this was in my .js code.  Much appreciate your help on this everyone.  I will add it to my styles.css code to see if it works and report back.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to put this in a JS file. You need to add this in a CSS file, say: `style.css` and the `style.css` file should be referenced as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

The above code has to be added to the `<head>` section of the HTML page.

If you need a JS only approach, you need to add it like this:

```
var css = '.fileactions > a:nth-child(2) {display: none;}',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
```

And your CSS says that, like said by [Jaaaaaaay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4922307/jaaaaaaay):

```
<div class="fileactions">
   <a>This is visible</a>
   <a>This is invisible</a> <!--it will hide this one-->
</div>
```

Hope this helps. Please read the introduction to HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in your css file, since

```
.fileactions > a:nth-child(2) {
   display: none;
}
```

means

```
 <div class="fileactions">
   <a>This is visible</a>
   <a>This is invisible</a> <!--it will hide this one-->
</div>
```

Comment: I referenced your answer buddy! `:D`

Answer (score 0):

This code is CSS, not javascript. You should add it to your .css file, or in a  tag in your page itself.